# C# Array of Classes

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am trying to make a console game where you enter as many names as you like up to 24. To do this I have created an array of a class called `PlayerData` named `PlayerDataAr[]` which has 24 elements. It prompts the user to enter some names and those names are assigned to each element in the array which a value of `string Name` and `bool isAlive` but for some reason I can't seem to be able to access these values while I am assigning them to the player.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hG
{
    public class PlayerData
    {
        private static bool _isAlive;
        public static bool isAlive
        {
            get { return _isAlive;}
            set { _isAlive = value;}
        }

        private static string _Name;
        public static string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }

        public PlayerData()
        {
            _isAlive = false;
            _Name = "";
        }

        public static void SetisAlive(bool a)
        {
            _isAlive = a;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string EnterName = "";

            //Array of Player Data
            PlayerData[] PlayerDataAr = new PlayerData[24];
            for (int x = 0; x < 24; x++ )
            {
                PlayerDataAr[x] = new PlayerData();
            }

            //Set up the Console
            Console.Title = "Hunger Games";
            Console.SetBufferSize(100, 42);
            Console.SetWindowSize(100, 42);

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.Clear();

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the names for tributes and press enter when done:");

            //Loop through collecting names
            for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("--> ");
                EnterName = Console.ReadLine();
                if (EnterName == "")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Assign Player Data
                    PlayerDataAr[x].Name = EnterName;        //Error appears here
                    PlayerDataAr[x].isAlive = true;          
                }                
            }
            Console.Clear();

            for (int x = 0; x < 24; x++)
            {

            }

            //Start Game
            while(true)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }    
        }
    }

}
```

It returns:

> Member 'hG.PlayerData.isAlive.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

I don't know what it is talking about it appears for both `Name` and `isAlive`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tried `get { return PlayerData._isAlive;}` ?

Comment: You could have found out about the problem by simply looking up what the static keyword means, which you are using in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove **static** from `PlayerData`:

```
public class PlayerData
{
    private bool _isAlive;
    public bool isAlive
    {
        get { return _isAlive;}
        set { _isAlive = value;}
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public PlayerData()
    {
        _isAlive = false;
        _Name = "";
    }

    public void SetisAlive(bool a)
    {
        _isAlive = a;
    }
}
```

A even better design is to use *auto implemented properties*:

```
public class PlayerData 
{
    public bool isAlive
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PlayerData()
    {
        isAlive = false; // redundant isAlive == false by default
        Name = "";
    }

    // redundant: you can easily put isAlive = value;
    public void SetisAlive(bool value)
    {
        isAlive = value;
    }
}
```

`static` means *class-based*: `PlayerData` as *a whole* has a *singular* `isAlive` property value. You want *different* behaviour: *each* `PlayerData` instance has *its own* property value, that's why `isAlive` should be just a *instance property* (no `static`).

Comment: Thank you, I suppose it was simple, I will make this the answer when I am allowed to

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it not only provided the fish, but also taught the OP how to fish (**EDIT** - sorry, that was maybe too abstract, if it not only told the OP they needed to remove `static`, but also *why* so that future readers understand what static does, and why it was incorrect in this case)

Answer (score 4):

You get error, because `isAlive` is `static`, which means it's not part of any instance. If you'd want to assign a value to your `isAlive` property you need to do this by type name:

```
PlayerData.isAlive = true;
```

**But** looking at your code, what you **really** want to do is remove `static` and access it through the instance reference:

```
private bool _isAlive;
public bool isAlive
{
    get { return _isAlive;}
    set { _isAlive = value;}
}
```

Then `PlayerDataAr[x].isAlive = true;` will work fine.

There is nice and simple explanation of `static` keyword [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static).